# What is the difference? "I wanted her to stop" vs "I wanted to stop her"

Tags: present-tense

Are they identical or not?

> I wanted her to stop.
>
> I wanted to stop her.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not a matter of preposition order. These two sentences have rather different structures.

> I wanted her to stop.

makes "her" the subject of the subordinate (non-finite clause): it is she that will be doing the stopping. You could paraphrase it "I wanted that she should stop".

> I wanted to stop her.

the subject of the subordinate clause is not stated, and is the same as the subject of the main clause. So this could be paraphrased as "I wanted that I should stop her".

[My paraphrases are grammatical, but not idiomatic: I've chosen them to make the meaning clear.]

**Edit:** John Lawler points out that, pragmatically, perhaps the paraphrase "I wanted that somebody or something should stop her" might capture the meaning better.

Comment: To continue your point, the second one seems to imply more "intervention" by the speaker. _I wanted her to stop singing_ could mean that you simply hoped she would stop singing soon. _I wanted to stop her singing_ (or perhaps _I wanted to stop her **from** singing_) might mean that you wanted to tell her to be quiet, or maybe even put duct tape over her mouth.

Comment: _I wanted to stop her singing_ is vague with regard to the desire of the speaker. They may want to take action or not, and they may want to prevent something, or they may simply want the noise to to stop.